# Make sure button is clicked when three EditText have a value

Tags: android, exception, android-edittext

I have 3 EditText which requires a value to be entered from a user. I want to make sure that all 3 EditText boxes have a value before user is able to click the button. If not then user must not be able to click the button. I tried using "setEnabled" or "setVisibility" but they throw an error instead.

```
EditText numA, numB, numC;

public static class QuadEquation extends Activity{
    Button calculate;
    EditText numA, numB, numC;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
        calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        numA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numA);
        numB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numB);
        numC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numC);

        try{

            calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                    Double a = (double) 0, b = (double) 0, c = (double) 0;

                    //Need to convert the string into double.
                    if (!(numA.getText().toString().equals("") && numB.getText().toString().equals("") && numC.getText().toString().equals(""))){
                        a = Double.parseDouble(numA.getText().toString());
                        b = Double.parseDouble(numB.getText().toString());
                        c = Double.parseDouble(numC.getText().toString());

                    }
```

Comment: Post the code u have done so far

Answer (score 1):

You should post the error you get if you want to do it that way and want us to help with the error.

Anyway, another way to do it is to check in your `onClick()` if they all have values

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
     if (et1.getText().toString.equals("") || et2.getText().toString.equals("") 
           || et3.getText().toString.equals(""))
     {
          // could print Toast to tell user to enter values or do something else
     }
     else
     {
          // do your work
     }
}
```

Comment: @ivesingh Please accept by clicking the checkmark if this worked for you so it may help others find it easier

Comment: -1 because; How does using onClick meet the OP requirement of checking that all 3 edit fields contain a value BEFORE the user is able to click the button?

Comment: @paulkayuk thanks for explaining the downvote. However, while it doesn't prevent the user clicking the `Button` it does give an alternate way of accomplishing the desired result. The OP doesn't want certain code to run if any boxes are empty. Sometimes someone will ask a question that isn't necessarily exactly what they need. By the OP's comment I would say this answer fulfills the needs. Its much like when you fill out a form and click a Button and you get a message saying that required fields are empty. Personally, I don't think it deserves a -1 because it isn't a wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

Implement a TextWatcher on your class and add a Text Changed Listener on each of your EditTexts e.g. ed1.addTextChangeListener(this). Then in the auto-generated method afterTextChanged check the length of the Text in each of your EditTexts. If all have lengths greater than 0 do calculate.setEnabled(true), having first initialised it on onCreate with calculate.setEnabled(false)

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
EditText ed1 =  findViewById(R.id.edit1);
EditText ed2 =  findViewById(R.id.edit2);
EditText ed3 =  findViewById(R.id.edit3);
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


String editString = ed1.getText().toString();
if(editString!= null){
  editString = ed2.getText().toString();
}
if(editString!= null){
  editString = ed3.getText().toString();
}

if(editString!= null){
  btn.setEnabled(true);
}
```

With a small correction.

Comment: @downvoters - And what's so wrong with this implementation that I got donvotet three times? Can you at least post a comment, I can be wrong somwhere, but just downvoting without a reason seems to be personal -huh?